# How do I extract specific parts of text from a string in R?

Tags: r, variables, extract

In R, I have variable which contains large strings of text for each row. From these strings, I'd like to extract specific parts, and add them to separate variables to my data frame. For example, one string value would look like:

```r
"identification"":""138""city"":""New-York"":COMMENT""text"":""Very good!""COMMENT""text"":""It was delicious""guests"":""2""
```

Desired result:

```r
    city      comment_text_1  comment_text_2
1   New-York  Very good!      It was delicious!
```

Each string differs in length and punctuation marks are being used throughout the string. Furthermore, there are some minor differences between the strings, for example, there might be another piece of text inbetween `city"":""` and `COMMENT""text"":""`

What might be a start, is that the text I need is always the text after `city"":""`, the first `COMMENT""text"":""` and the second `COMMENT""text"":""`. Furthermore, the text I need always ends with two quotation marks `""`

Comment: Look into a tutorial for regex. It’s painful - good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mark Neal mentioned, this is a task you can solve by using regular expressions. I'm not very skilled in using regex, but perhaps I can give you some insights:

```r
library(tidyverse)
text <- c('"identification"":""138""city"":""New-York"":COMMENT""text"":""Very good!""COMMENT""text"":""It was delicious""guests"":""2""')

city <- text %>% str_extract('(?<=city"":"").*(?="":COMMENT"")')
comment_1 <- text %>% str_extract('(?<=COMMENT""text"":"").*(?=""COMMENT"")')
comment_2 <- text %>% str_extract('(?<=COMMENT""text"":"").*(?=""guests"")') %>% str_extract('(?<=COMMENT""text"":"").*')

df <- data.frame(city=city, comment_1=comment_1, comment_2=comment_2)
```

What did I do?

#### city

```r
str_extract('(?<=city"":"").*(?="":COMMENT"")')
```

I search for `city"":""` and `"":COMMENT""` and return everything inbetween:

```r
[1] "New-York"
```

#### comment 1

```r
comment_1 <- text %>% str_extract('(?<=COMMENT""text"":"").*(?=""COMMENT"")')
```

Same for `COMMENT""text"":""` and `""COMMENT""` which yields

```r
[1] "Very good!"
```

#### comment 2

Since I couldn't figure out how to get the desired result with one regex, I had to iterate.

```r
comment_2 <- text %>% str_extract('(?<=COMMENT""text"":"").*(?=""guests"")') %>% str_extract('(?<=COMMENT""text"":"").*')
```

The first iteration `COMMENT""text"":""` and `""guests""` returns

```r
[1] "Very good!\"\"COMMENT\"\"text\"\":\"\"It was delicious"
```

since the regex is greedy i.e. it returns the maximum possible string matching the pattern.
So the next iteration with `COMMENT""text"":""` only returns just the desired last comment:

```r
[1] "It was delicious"
```